# How to display all the lines from the nth line of a file in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I want to display all the lines starting from the nth line. Say, print the third line of a file and all the following lines until end of file. Is there a command for that?

Answer (score 70):

you can use tail

excerpt from the manpage:

> ```
>    -n, --lines=K
>          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to
>          output lines starting with the Kth
> ```

for example

```
tail -n +10 file
```

outputs the files content starting with the 10th line

Comment: Good one i wasn't aware of that tail functionality

Comment: @Auspex: Not sure if you were trying to be funny there :-).  It's not that SO is faster; there isn't a manpage that would answer the stated goals of the poster. As a decades-long user, hell I didn't know tail did this (I would have turned to what I know, a one-liner awk or Perl snippet).

Comment: @Crossfit_and_Beer Not trying to be funny; I think I wrote that right after seeing somebody else complain that a question could have been answered if the person just read the man page; and I pointed out that since said question didn't seem to have been answered here before, it was perfectly appropriate to have it, and an answer on SO. 'coz this is the place to go for answers.  But there _is_ a manpage that answers the OP's question. The `tail` manpage!

Comment: @Auspex: `But there is a manpage that answers the OP's question. The tail manpage!`.  No, his question specifically mentioned `Is there a command for that?` which clearly suggests he doesn't know 'what' the relevant _command name_ is.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a file but with terminal output? For example I'm trying to do `tail -n +6 $(git status), which I hoped would give me a list of the files that had been edited, but instead actually goes into the files themselves and takes from the 6th line, which isn't quite what I'm after

Comment: Got it `git status -s | cut -c 4- | xargs code`

Answer (score 16):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -n '3,$p' file
```

This selects line 3 to the end and prints it.

Comment: Instead of filling your answer with rubbish, you could have explained what the syntax represents.

Comment: Hehe, it represents an answer to the question, which is what the OP asked for.  If they wanted to learn sed, this isn't the forum for that, is it?

Answer (score 15):

To show from 5th line:

```
awk 'NR>4' file
```

Comment: Minor nitpick. It will show from 6th line onwards but +1 none the less.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Not sure who down voted your good answer. Hopefully others realize and push it up.

Answer (score 5):

Print, but delete lines 1 through 2:

```
sed '1,2d' filename
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=5}NR<=n{next}1' file
```

- `BEGIN{n=5}` - before file processing starts, sets `n` to the number of lines to skip (5).
- `NR<=n{next}` - skips processing if the line number is less than or equal to `n`.
- `1` - shorthand for `print` everything else.

Comment: The shortest would be `awk 'NR>5' file` but since that has already been suggested, I would like to add that `awk` just like `sed` supports range operator. So, `awk 'NR==5,0' file` will work as well.

Answer (score 4):

The `awk` command can do this by only printing lines to the `NR` record number is three or more:

```
awk 'NR>=3' input_file_name
```

You can also pass the value into `awk` using a variable if need be:

```
awk -v n=3 'NR>=n' input_file_name
```

(and you can use `-v n=${num}` to use an environment variable as well).

There are many other tools you can use to do the same job, `tail`, `sed` and `perl` among them or, since this is a programming Q&A site, just roll your own:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    // Need character and # of newlines to skip.

    int ch, newlines = 2;

    // Loop until EOF or first lines skipped, exit on EOF.

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        if ((ch == '\n') && (--newlines == 0))
            break;

    if (ch == EOF)
        return 0;

    // Now just echo all other characters, then return.

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar (ch);

    return 0;
}
```

Now you wouldn't normally write your own filter program for this but, since you asked for the shortest command, you could use that source code to create an executable called `x` to do it:

```
x <input_file_name
```

You'd be hard-pressed finding a shorter command than that. Of course, assuming you're in a UNIXy environment (specifically, `bash`), you could also just:

```
alias x awk 'NR>=3'
```

:-)

Comment: The `{print}` is implied if you don't put anything so `awk 'NR>=3' file` will do.

Comment: The `export` serves no useful purpose here.

Comment: @tripleee: right on the first count (so changed), irrelevant on the second. Whether it's exported or not, I was just showing how to use a shell variable. Have adjusted the answer to remove that anyway.